# choose specific shapefiles for input

Tags: r, shapefile

I have a folder with a variety of shapefiles like these:

- 1965_120m.shp,
- 1967_120m.shp,
- 1968_120m.shp,
- 1965_50m.shp,
- 1967_50m.shp,
- 1968_50m.shp,
- 1965_10m.shp,
- 1967_10m.shp,
- 1968_10m.shp

(The data on the folder are much more and this is just an example) so I struggle myself to find a way to select all the shapefiles of 50 meters from this folder.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Is this about selecting files based upon their name, if it "50m" or not? How does this need to be be done? Using a GUI using choose.files? You need to provide more context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a reproducible example it will be difficult to provide a complete solution, but...

```
filenames <- list.files(path=".", pattern="50m.shp", ignore.case = TRUE, recursive = FALSE, include.dirs = FALSE)
```

should get you your files and...

```
for( f in filenames ){
#do stuff with each file (f) such as mySHP <- readOGR( ... layer = file_path_sans_ext(f) )
}
```

will do your stuff with each file in turn

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be what i was looking for, but what I do not understand is the input on layer.... The file path suppose to be the first input of the readOGR function. This is your script adapted to my needs and some more details for help...

```
input_folder<- "C:/Users/Data_Analysis/R data processing/points_rastervalue"

output_folder<- "C:/Users/Data_Analysis/R data processing/output"

setwd("C:/Users/Data_Analysis/R data processing/points_rastervalue")

shps <- list.files(path=".", pattern="50m.shp", ignore.case = TRUE, recursive = FALSE, include.dirs = FALSE)

for( shp in shps ){
  mySHP <- readOGR('.', layer = ?? )
}
```

Comment: `mySHP <- readOGR('.', layer = file_path_sans_ext(shp) )` should do it since you already set your working directory.  Realize that this is a loop and you need to do your processing and saving of the output within the loop as well otherwise it will just open each file in turn and overwrite mySHP.

Comment: To just open (for example) the first file in the list use: `mySHP <- readOGR('.', layer = file_path_sans_ext(shps[1]) )` and NOT inside the  `for( shp in shps ){ }` loop.

Comment: For saving the output should I use a function like the assign/sapply/lapply within the loop? (as long as my further aim is to use the selected shapefiles to make a brick )

Comment: "make a brick"  = merging the shapefiles? it depends on what the shapefiles are.  For point files, `rbind()` within the loop will combine them together one by one, then after the loop you would `writeOGR()` to save the combined file